# WinMain/Win32 Window not displaying, but shows up in Processes tab of Task Manager

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, winmain

I'm a newbie to c++, and I'm stuck on displaying the window. I'm not getting any errors, but my Window is not displaying on the desktop. When I open the task manager, it appears under the 'Proccesses' tab. I haven't been finding any solutions to this problem, so any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

**Note: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012
**Note: Not exactly a newbie to c++, but more to creating a win32 application

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

static TCHAR WindowClass[] = L"Window";

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
    HWND   WinH,
    UINT   Msg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT pntStruct;
        static HDC hdc;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            BeginPaint(
                WinH,
                &pntStruct
            );
            TextOut(hdc,
                5, 5,
                L"Hello, World!", _tcslen(L"Hello, World!"));
            //pntStruct.rcPaint
            EndPaint(
                WinH,
                &pntStruct
            );

        } break;

        case WM_SIZE:
        {

        } break;

        case WM_MOVE:
        {

        } break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {

        } break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {

        } break;

        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(WinH, Msg, wParam, lParam);
        } break;

        case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
        {
            if (WM_ACTIVATEAPP)
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_ACTIVEAPP->TRUE");
            }
            else
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_ACTIVEAPP->FALSE");
            }
        } break;

    }

    return 0;
};


int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE Window,
    HINSTANCE PrevInstance,
    LPSTR     Cmd,
    int       CmdShow
    )
{

    WNDCLASSEX wclass;
        //wclass.cbSize =  sizeof(WNDCLASS);
        wclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
        wclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
        wclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wclass.hInstance = Window;
        //wclass.hIcon; TODO: CREATE ICON
        //wclass.hCursor;
        //wclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        wclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wclass.lpszClassName = (LPCTSTR)WindowClass;
//      HICON     hIconSm;
        RegisterClassEx(&wclass);

    HWND CreateWin = CreateWindow(
        WindowClass,
        L"NAME OF WINDOW",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,//WIDTH:[TODO]->Make custom width to fit window
        CW_USEDEFAULT,//HEIGHT:[TODO]->Make custom width to fit window
        0,
        0,
        Window,
        0
    );

    ShowWindow(CreateWin, CmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(CreateWin);

    MSG message;

    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    };

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Does it appear  on task-bar  ?

Comment: Yah. I believe I stated that in a confusing manner, sorry about that. It shows up in the proccesses tab as 'Window.exe'

Comment: No, I mean doesn't it show up on task-**bar**. The horizontal panel on the bottom of the screen (normally). Probably your window is just misplaced, and you just need to move it to visible area

Comment: Oh. No, but could it be that I'm using a multidesktop Program? I've checked the other desktops and it's not there, but could it be causing a bug? I'm using 'Desktops v2.0'

Comment: Can you check what is the return value of `CreateWindow`  ? Just set a break-point on that line and debug

Comment: You never initialise `hdc` with the result of the `BeginPaint` call, so your painting will fail.

Comment: If you're beginning to learn C++ ,the worst thing you can do is trying to use GUI-programming. Learn C++ by using the console ,that is difficult enough. You're doing so many thing wrong that I don't know where to begin.

Comment: The CreateWin value returns {unused=262570632} Don't know if that helps.

Comment: You aren't performing any error checking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lots of things wrong with this code.

You are declaring `WindowClass` as a `TCHAR[]`, but initializing it with a `wchar_t[]`.  Same thing with the `lpString` parameter of `TextOut()`.  That will only work if `UNICODE` is defined for the project, otherwise you will get a compiler error.  When you use `TCHAR`, you need to wrap string literals with the `TEXT()` macro so they use the correct character type.  Otherwise, stop using `TCHAR` and just use Unicode APIs for everything.  You only need to use `TCHAR` if your code needs to support both ANSI (Win9x/ME) and Unicode (NT4+) compilations.  Nobody really supports Win9x/Me anymore, so new code should focus on just Unicode APIs.

You are not zeroing the contents of the `WNDCLASSEX` structure, so all of the fields that you have intentionally commented out and not assigned values to (most importantly, the `cbSize` field) will contain *random values* from the stack.  That is likely to cause `RegisterClassEx()` to fail, which you are not checking for.  To avoid this problem, ALWAYS zero out API structures before using them.  This is especially important for structures that grow in size over time (when newer Windows releases introduce new structure fields).  Such structures typically have a `cbSize` field so the API knows which version of the structure you are using, so you must provide an accurate value.  And you need to zero out any unused fields so you do not get unexpected behavior from the API.

You are not checking if `CreateWindow()` fails, such as a side effect of `RegisterClassEx()` failing.

Your `WindowProc()` is supposed to pass unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc()`, but you are not doing that.  Most of your `case` blocks are simply discarding messages so Windows cannot process them.  Is that what you really want?  I doubt it.  In particular, the default behavior of `DefWindowProc()` for `WM_CLOSE` is to destroy the window, triggering the `WM_DESTROY` message.

Your `WM_DESTROY` handler is not calling `PostQuitMessage()` to put a `WM_QUIT` message into the calling thread's message queue so `GetMessage()` can return 0 to break your message loop and let the app exit.

Your `WM_PAINT` handler is not using the `HDC` that `BeginPaint()` provides to you, you are drawing using an uninitialized `HDC` variable.

With all of that said, try something more like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h> // Or: remove this

static TCHAR WindowClass[] = TEXT("Window");
// or: static WCHAR WindowClass[] = L"Window";

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            static const TCHAR* HelloWorld = TEXT("Hello, World!");
            // or: const WCHAR* HelloWorld = L"Hello, World!";

            PAINTSTRUCT pntStruct = {0};
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &pntStruct);

            TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, HelloWorld, _tcslen(HelloWorld));
            // or: TextOutW(hdc, 5, 5, HelloWorld, lstrlenW(HelloWorld));

            EndPaint(hWnd, &pntStruct);
            break;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            //...
            break;
        }

        case WM_MOVE:
        {
            //...
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            //...
            break;
        }

        case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
        {
            if (WM_ACTIVATEAPP)
            {
                OutputDebugString(TEXT("WM_ACTIVEAPP->TRUE"));
                // or: OutputDebugStringW(L"WM_ACTIVEAPP->TRUE");
            }
            else
            {
                OutputDebugString(TEXT("WM_ACTIVEAPP->FALSE"));
                // or: OutputDebugStringW(L"WM_ACTIVEAPP->FALSE");
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wclass = {0}; // Or: WNDCLASSEXW
    wclass.cbSize = sizeof(wclass);
    wclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wclass.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc;
    wclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wclass.hIcon = NULL; // TODO: CREATE ICON
    wclass.hCursor = NULL;
    wclass.hbrBackground = NULL;//(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wclass.lpszClassName = WindowClass;
    wclass.hIconSm = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wclass)) // Or: RegisterClassExW()
    {
        // error! Use GetLastError() to find out why...
        return 0;
    }

    HWND hCreateWin = CreateWindow( // Or: CreateWindowW()
        WindowClass,
        TEXT("NAME OF WINDOW"), // Or: L"NAME OF WINDOW"
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,//WIDTH:[TODO]->Make custom width to fit window
        CW_USEDEFAULT,//HEIGHT:[TODO]->Make custom width to fit window
        0,
        0,
        hInstance,
        0
    );

    if (!hCreateWin)    
    {
        // error! Use GetLastError() to find out why...
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hCreateWin, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hCreateWin);

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    };

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Holy cow this is well written! I wish I had read this instead of 15 minutes of Googleing! Thank you for taking the time to write this. I only wish I could up vote this! But maybe a later time I'll be able to. As you said, setting the default of my `WNDCLASS` to zero would help with it. Thanks again!

Comment: Zeroing it, and also setting its `cbSize` field to `sizeof(wclass)`. That is mandatory, you cannot skip it.